# I am typing in one input box gets text on all input box

Tags: javascript

This image describe my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx25q.png)

Good Morning,
Actually, I am using the keyboard plugin. It's good for the single input box. Because if it takes direct id ('itemNo_2') from it the value goes in which 'id' I have taken. But if we take (': input') instead of ('itemNo_2') so that thing happening here. Typing in one input box gets text on all input box

Please give me some suggestion. I am taking too much time in it, but I have not got a good solution.

```
$(function(){
        var $write = $(':input'),       
        shift = false,
        capslock = false;
        backspace  = false;
    $('#keyboard li').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            character = $this.html(); 

        // Shift keys
        if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            $('.symbol span').toggle();

            shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
            capslock = false;
            backspace  = false;
            return false;
        }

        // Caps lock
        if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            capslock = true;
            return false;
        }

        // backspace lock
        if ($this.hasClass('backspace')) {
            $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
            capslock = true;
            return false;
        }

        // Delete
            if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
                var html = $write.html(),
                txt = html.substr(0, html.length - 1);
              $write.html(txt);
              $write.autocomplete("search", txt);
              return false;
            }
            // Delete

        // Special characters
        if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
        if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
        if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
        if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";

        // Uppercase letter
        if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();

        // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
        if (shift === true) {
            $('.symbol span').toggle();
            if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

            shift = false;
        }
        //console.log("DO IT ", character);
        // Add the character
        $write.val($write.val() + character);       
        $write.html(txt);
        $write.autocomplete("search", txt);


    }); 

});
```

Its plugin part

```
 $(function () {
     var write = write();       
     write.init("keyboard");
     //first input focus
     var $firstInput = $(":input").first().focus();
     write.currentElement = $firstInput;
     write.currentElementCursorPosition = 0;
 });
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: anybody solve this issues

Comment: Vivek, You need to create a working snippet using `<>` of your toolbar that replicate your problem. Also, go through the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and **how to ask** (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: probably you have an issue with your selectors post a working plunker

Comment: Try `var $write = $(':input:focus'),` instead of `var $write = $(':input'),`

Comment: dear @gurvinder372 sir, its not working